# Pivoting with grouby?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot, aggregation

I wonder if you can help me to find a solution for the following problem. Given a data frame df1 like this

```py
d1={'L':['aaa','bbb','ccc','aaa','bbb','ddd'],
'w':[1,5,9,13,17,21],
'x':[2,6,10,14,18,22],
'y':[3,7,11,15,19,23],
'z':[4,8,12,16,20,24]}
df1=pd.DataFrame(d1)
```

[image: Data]

and two dictionaries to define grouping over columns and rows

```py
dctRowGroups={'aaa':'A','bbb':'B','ccc':'A','ddd':'B'}
dctColGroups={'w':'ALPHA','x':'BETA','y':'ALPHA','z':'BETA'}
```

I wanted to aggregate over columns as a first step. Applying

```py
g2=df1.groupby(dctColGroups,axis=1)
g2.sum()
```

results in

[image: Result of grouping by column]

but I wanted to keep the 'L' column for the next step row-wise aggregation, i.e. the result should be a dataframe df2 more like this:

[image: Result I wanted to get]

What do I need to code to make this happen?
As a next step, I want to aggregate df2 over the rows using the dctRowGroups dictionary

```py
g3=df2.groupby(dctRowGroups,axis=0)
g3.sum()
```

to get a final result like this:

[image: Final result]

In what way can I do all these steps in as few lines of code as possible?
Appreciate your advice on this.

Thanks a lot

Willfried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

Firstly create df2 and insert 'L' column by using `insert()` method:

```
df2=df1.groupby(dctColGroups,axis=1).sum()

df2.insert(0,'L',df1['L'])  #use this only when the order matters

#OR(use anyone of the method either insert or assign)

df2=df2.assign(L=df1['L'])  #otherwise use this
```

Finally use `assign()` ,`map()` and `groupby()` method:

```
result=df2.assign(L=df2['L'].map(dctRowGroups)).groupby('L').sum()
```

Outputs:

`df2`**:**

```
    L   ALPHA   BETA
0   aaa     4   6
1   bbb     12  14
2   ccc     20  22
3   aaa     28  30
4   bbb     36  38
5   ddd     44  46
```

`result`**:**

```
    ALPHA   BETA
L       
A   52      58
B   92      98
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works! What I would like to better understand is why in the second step a simple "result=df2.groupby(dctRowGroups,axis=0)" does deliver the same result as "result=df2.assign(L=df2['L'].map(dctRowGroups)).groupby('L').sum()"?

Comment: If this answer solved your query then pls try consider to accept this answer...Thnx **:)**

Comment: On my side `result=df2.groupby(dctRowGroups,axis=0)` this is throwing an error so I used `result=df2.assign(L=df2['L'].map(dctRowGroups)).groupby('L').sum()`

Comment: Ah, ok. I decomposed result=df2.assign(L=df2['L'].map(dctRowGroups)).groupby('L').sum() into individual steps to better understand what is going on. It's clear now: one needs to replace the old labels in column 'L' with the new one's from dctRowGroups, re-insert it as column 'L' into the DataFrame, and then apply the groupby('L').sum() to that new DataFrame.

Comment: yes.....`df2['L'].map(dctRowGroups)` this will replace keys of `dctRowGroups` inside `'L'` column to its values(its basically called mapping) and `assign()` method i.e: `df2.assign(L=df2['L'].map(dctRowGroups))`  will assign those mapped values to column `'L'` then we groupby column `'L'` i.e:  `groupby('L')` and calculate sum by `sum()` method